# Is there a clean way to remove the SignalR Javascript package from my project, but keep the .net DLL's?

Tags: visual-studio, signalr, nuget

A personal preference of mine is to pull javascript libraries down from a CDN as opposed to hosting them locally.

I also like to use Nuget. I have installed the SignalR Nuget package into an MVC project, but am trying to use the package manager to remove the Javascript component to keep things tidy, however Nuget tells me I can't remove `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS` without removing `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` also.

It's not a massive deal, I can just leave the files there and use a CDN anyway, but it is a bit annoying.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, instead of using the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` package, you just use `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core`, which is just the .NET server side portion, and then grab the SignalR JS client from the CDN as you are already doing. You can remove `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` as a whole safely, and then install the `Core` one.